# How to split strings across multiple lines in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I usually have a policy in my project, to never create lines in text files that exceed a line length of 80, so they are easily editable in all kinds of editors (you know the deal). But with CMake I get the problem that I do not know how to split a simple string into multiple lines to avoid one huge line. Consider this basic code:

```
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA "rc1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}-${VERSION_EXTRA}")
```

It already exceeds the 80 column limit. So how do I break a line in CMake into multiple lines without getting to verbose (multiple `list(APPEND ...)` or the like)?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Update for **CMake 3.0 and newer** :

line continuation is possible with `\`. see [the latest cmake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument)

```
message("\
This is the first line of a quoted argument. \
In fact it is the only line but since it is long \
the source code uses line continuation.\
")
```

#### Availability of CMake versions:

Debian Wheezy (2013): 2.8.9
Debian Wheezy-backports: 2.8.11
Debian Jessy (2015): 3.0.2
Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS): 2.8.12
Ubuntu 15.04 : 3.0.2
Mac OSX : cmake-3 available through [Homebrew](http://braumeister.org/formula/cmake), [Macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=cmake) and [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/cmake)
Windows: cmake-3 available through [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cmake)

Comment: Problem with the CMake 3.0 approach is that it doesn't ignore indentation. Which means multi-line strings can't be indented with the rest of the code.

Comment: @void.pointer I ran into the same problem, did you figure out how to indent with multi-line?

Comment: Also if want to use indentation and are 80 char limit bound then another way is to do like this:

<code>
message("This is the value of the variable: " <br>
                "${varValue}")
</code>

Answer (score 71):

### CMake 3.0 and newer

Use the `string(CONCAT)` command:

```
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA "rc1")
string(CONCAT MYPROJ_VERSION "${MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR}"
                             ".${MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR}"
                             ".${MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH}"
                             "-${MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA}")
```

Although CMake 3.0 and newer support [line continuation of quoted arguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument), you cannot indent the second or subsequent lines without getting the indentation whitespace included in your string.

### CMake 2.8 and older

You can use a list. Each element of the list can be put on a new line:

```
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA "rc1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_LIST "${MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR}"
                        ".${MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR}"
                        ".${MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH}"
                        "-${MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA}")
```

A list used without quotes is concatenated without white-space:

```
message(STATUS "Version: " ${MYPROJ_VERSION_LIST})
-- Version: 1.0.0-rc1
```

If you really need a string, you can convert the list to a string first:

```
string(REPLACE ";" "" MYPROJ_VERSION "${MYPROJ_VERSION_LIST}")
message(STATUS "Version: ${MYPROJ_VERSION}")
-- Version: 1.0.0-rc1
```

Any semicolons in your original strings will be seen as list element separators, and removed. They must be escaped:

```
set(MY_LIST "Hello World "
            "with a \;semicolon")
```

Comment: For very long lines, a newline after the variable name even further improves this pattern (unnecessary in this example).

Comment: Out of [curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229315/write-c-file-with-cmake), would it be correct to guess that double quotes in the string also need to be escaped with a backslash, and so do any backslashes that need to appear as a character in the string?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, they would need escaping. Language rules are here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#escape-sequences but it does get confusing. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728463

Answer (score 12):

The example in the original question is only about a relatively short string. For longer strings (including the examples given in other answers), a [bracket argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#bracket-argument) could be better. From the documentation:

> An opening bracket is written `[` followed by zero or more `=` followed by `[`. The corresponding closing bracket is written `]` followed by the same number of `=` followed by `]`. Brackets do not nest. A unique length may always be chosen for the opening and closing brackets to contain closing brackets of other lengths.
>
> [...]
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> message([=[
> This is the first line in a bracket argument with bracket length 1.
> No \-escape sequences or ${variable} references are evaluated.
> This is always one argument even though it contains a ; character.
> The text does not end on a closing bracket of length 0 like ]].
> It does end in a closing bracket of length 1.
> ]=])
> ```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, A linebreak in the source will also introduce a linebreak in the string. For example, there will be a \n after the "length 1.". Any way to avoid that?

Comment: That's correct, there will be `\n`s. If you don't want that, I don't think that bracket arguments are your solution.

Comment: BTW, it is valid for version 3.x, not 2.x

Answer (score 11):

For those who were brought here from [How do I split a CMake generator expression to multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51371781/12679439) I would like to add some notes.

The line continuation method will not work, CMake cannot parse a generator list made with whitespace (indentation) and line continuation.

While the string(CONCAT) solution will provide a generator expression that can be evaluated, the evaluated expression will be surrounded by quotes if the result contains a space.

For each individual option to be added a separate generator list must be constructed, so stacking options like I have done in the following will cause the build to fail:

```
string(CONCAT WARNING_OPTIONS "$<"
    "$<OR:"
        "$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,"
        "$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID},MSVC>"
    ">:"
    "/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS "
">$<"
    "$<AND:"
        "$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang,GNU>,"
        "$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID},MSVC>>"
    ">:"
    "-Wall -Werror "
">$<"
    "$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:"
    "-Wno-multichar -Wno-sign-compare "
">")
add_compile_options(${WARNING_OPTIONS})
```

This is because the resulting options are passed to the compiler in quotes

```
/usr/lib64/ccache/c++  -DGTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1 -Dgtest_EXPORTS -I../ThirdParty/googletest/googletest/include -I../ThirdParty/googletest/googletest -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fPIC    -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wshadow -DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=1 -fexceptions -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers "-Wall -Werror -Wno-multichar -Wno-sign-compare " -fdiagnostics-color -MD -MT ThirdParty/googletest/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o -MF ThirdParty/googletest/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o.d -o ThirdParty/googletest/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o -c ../ThirdParty/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wall -Werror -Wno-multichar -Wno-sign-compare ’
```

To evaluate lengthy generator expressions represented using the string(CONCAT) solution, each generator expression must evaluate to a single option with no spaces:

```
string(CONCAT WALL "$<"
    "$<AND:"
        "$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang,GNU>,"
        "$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID},MSVC>>"
    ">:"
    "-Wall"
">")
string(CONCAT WERROR "$<"
    "$<AND:"
        "$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang,GNU>,"
        "$<NOT:$<STREQUAL:${CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID},MSVC>>"
    ">:"
    "-Werror"
">")
message(STATUS "Warning Options: " ${WALL} ${WERROR})
add_compile_options(${WALL} ${WERROR})
```

This may be unrelated to the question I am posting an answer to,  unfortunately the question I am answering is wrongfully marked as a duplicate of this question.

Generator lists are not handled and parsed the same way as strings are, and because of this, there are additional measures one must take to split a generator list across multiple lines.

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to also post a version of this answer on the linked "duplicate". This was the answer I was looking for when I came across it.

Comment: Where is the maintainable version of this mess?

Comment: Not related to the syntax problem, but I think your example code should probably use CXX_COMPILER_FRONTEND_VARIANT.

Answer (score 9):

It's still a little verbose, but if the 80 char limit really bugs you then you could repeatedly append to the same variable:

```
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA "rc1")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${MYPROJ_VERSION_MAJOR}.")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${MYPROJ_VERSION}${MYPROJ_VERSION_MINOR}.")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${MYPROJ_VERSION}${MYPROJ_VERSION_PATCH}-")
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${MYPROJ_VERSION}${MYPROJ_VERSION_EXTRA}")
message(STATUS "version: ${MYPROJ_VERSION}")
```

Gives output:

```
$ cmake  ~/project/tmp
-- version: 1.0.0-rc1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rsanderson/build/temp
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to split a string literal across multiple lines in CMakeLists.txt files or in CMake scripts. If you include a newline within a string, there will be a literal newline in the string itself.

```
# Don't do this, it won't work, MYPROJ_VERSION will contain newline characters:
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${VERSION_MAJOR}.
  ${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}-
  ${VERSION_EXTRA}")
```

However, CMake uses whitespace to separate arguments, so you can change a space that's an argument separator into a newline anywhere you like, without changing the behavior.

You could re-phrase this longer line:

```
set(MYPROJ_VERSION "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}-${VERSION_EXTRA}")
```

as these two shorter lines:

```
set(MYPROJ_VERSION
  "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}-${VERSION_EXTRA}")
```

They are entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

To maintain good indentation in your code it's straightforward enough just to do

```
message("These strings " "will all be "
        "concatenated. Don't forget "
        "your trailing spaces!")
```

Or form a string directly with

```
string(CONCAT MYSTR "This and " "that "
                    "and me too!")
```

as in [Douglas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16703203) who has more details. However I thought this might just summarise the essential point.