# CMake: How to set different debug commands for different build configurations correctly?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I tried using the `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND` property with generator expressions.

According to the CMake manual it should work: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND.html

My CMake script is the following:

```
set_property(TARGET ${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/bin/maya.exe">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release2017>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/bin/maya.exe">
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release2018>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe">
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2019>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/bin/maya.exe">
    $<$<CONFIG:Release2019>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/bin/maya.exe">
)
```

What I got for the `Debug2018` configuration for the Debugger command is:

```
Command                 ;;"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe";;;
```

which is not correct of course.

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generator expressions placed on multiple lines is interpreted *differently* by CMake than placing them all on one line (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371781/how-do-i-split-a-cmake-generator-expression-to-multiple-lines)). In this case, for [`set_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html), CMake interprets the multi-line generator expression as a **list**. Therefore, for the `Debug2018` configuration, one list entry evaluates to the `maya.exe` path, while the others evaluate to empty strings. All are placed in a semicolon-separated list.

To prevent CMake from interpreting the expression as a list, place the *entire* generator expression on one line:

```
set_property(TARGET ${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/bin/maya.exe">$<$<CONFIG:Release2017>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/bin/maya.exe">$<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe">$<$<CONFIG:Release2018>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe">$<$<CONFIG:Debug2019>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/bin/maya.exe">$<$<CONFIG:Release2019>:"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/bin/maya.exe">
)
```

You could also use CMake's [`string(CONCAT ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#concat) command to construct the generator expression as a single string, then pass this string to the `set_property()` command:

```
string(CONCAT MY_CONFIG_GENEX
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug2017>:\"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/bin/maya.exe\">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release2017>:\"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2017/bin/maya.exe\">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug2018>:\"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe\">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release2018>:\"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/bin/maya.exe\">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug2019>:\"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/bin/maya.exe\">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release2019>:\"C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/bin/maya.exe\">"
)
set_property(TARGET ${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND
    ${MY_CONFIG_GENEX}
)
```

In this case, you must escape the quotes around the `maya.exe` path with backslashes (e.g. `\"...\"`).