# Can I use .clang-tidy file with CMakeList.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang

I have linked clang for my cpp project with CMakeLists.txt with

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-checks=google-*,cppcoreguidelines-*")
```

Since, I would like to move all the clang config to a file, I googled little bit
and found that there is .clang-tidy file for this usage.

However, I wasn't able to configure CMakeList.txt to actually use this file.

Can anyone tell me how I should change that line in CMakeList.txt to link it with .clang-tidy file?

Comment: Not sure how to include .clang-tidy file. But you can put `set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-checks=google-*,cppcoreguidelines-*")` in a separate cmake file(for example clang-tidy.cmake) and include it  in main `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @JohnKoch Do you know if there is any way of adding filter externally? or in a more organized way than putting them all into a single line?

Comment: cmake does support multi line string since version 3.0. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983206/5360439

Comment: @JohnKoch seems like you know clang-tidy well, would you be able to take a look at this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61001314/13200816

Answer (score 5):

If you have `.clang-tidy` in project root, all you need to do is specify `clang-tidy` executable, e.g.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy")
```

and `clang-tidy` will implicitly use `.clang-tidy`.